# Как использовать Preference для сохранения данных при использовании SurfaceView?

Tags: android

Хотелось бы реализовать сохранение данных при помощи использования Preferecnce. Но при попытке использовать метод

```
mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

студия ругается на `getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Однако при использовании XML Activity студия спокойно распознает данный метод.

Что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSharedPreferences` - это метод класса `Context`, активити - наследник контекста и в ней можно вызывать этот метод напрямую, во вьюхе надо вызывать его у контекста.

```
mSettings = getContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```